# Application has stopped unexpectedly in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on Google Map application in android, there is no error when I run my application but when my application launch on emulator I see the following message.

```
The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.
```

Is there any debug mode in android so that I can find actual problem.

I am using Eclipse and AVD for Andorid application development.

Comment: Switch to DDMS perspective, then click on Logcat here you will see all the debug, warning and error logs. Whenever Android throws any exception, it generates its error log in the DDMS which tells us about the problem. Paste that stack trace here, so that we can better understand the problem.

Comment: you can run your app in debug mode can you post your logcat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is debug mode in Eclipse.

First put break point at any line of code in android application.

Now Right Click on your Application through **Package Explorer** & Click on **Debug As-> Android Application.**

Then wait for while when debugger settles on android phone (you can see this in **Log Cat** of **DDMS Perspective**).LogCat is available through Window->Show View->Log Cat In DDMS Persprective.

Comment: Will help newcomer to understand the debug of Android Application.